# Find all highest values of a column in an SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select all the rows with the highest number, which is 293 in this case. However, it could be any number as I don't know it up front. So a simple where clause won't be sufficient. I already tried something with MAX() but that only took 1 row while I need all of them. Can anyone help me?

```
ID     NUMBER
1       293
2       293
3       293
4       148
5       96
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very basic:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE NUMBER = (SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM YourTable);
```

Answer (score 2):

A typical method is to use window functions:

```
select id, number
from (select t.*, max(number) over () as maxn
      from t
     ) t
where number = maxn;
```